# Agrupar datos de consulta mysql por fecha

Tags: mysql

Este el es resultado que obtengo con la consulta mas abajo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9qAx.png

Este es el resultado que necesitaría obtener
https://i.stack.imgur.com/asqt5.png

Utilizando la siguiente consulta obtengo el primer resultado en la imagen pero al agregar Group by me da error this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT DATE(p.fecha), p.id1, v.id2, v.producto_nombre,
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 1 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda1',
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 2 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda2',
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 3 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda3',
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 4 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda4',
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 5 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda5',
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 6 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda6',
CASE WHEN p.tienda_id = 9 THEN p.precio_valor END AS 'tienda7'
FROM precios p
JOIN variante v ON v.id1 = 1954
WHERE p.id2 = 123
AND DATE(p.fecha) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
AND CURDATE()
```

Si me dan una mano por favor! Gracias!

Comment: Intentaste con un Distinct?

Comment: Mismo resultado que la primera imagen

Comment: Puedes colocar tu query y una bd de prueba aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/ para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar tu problema puedes utilizar una subconsulta. De manera que la consulta contenga el agrupamiento y la subconsulta el WHERE original.

Similar a:

```
SELECT fecha, id1, id2, producto_nombre, tienda_id FROM (
    SELECT DATE(p.fecha) as fecha, p.id1, v.id2, v.producto_nombre, p.tienda_id
     FROM precios p
     JOIN variante v ON v.id1 = 1954
     WHERE p.id2 = 123
     AND DATE(p.fecha) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
     AND CURDATE()) as A
GROUP BY tienda_id, producto_nombre, fecha, id1, id2
```

Comment: Hola Juan! en parte me ayuda el código, solo que me pierdo con el sub select y agregando los CASE statement que tengo en mi consulta, me ayudas si podrías explicando y ejemplificando con los CASE aplicando el sub select que me recomiendas? Muchas gracias!!